# How to install kitkat in oppo?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.2-jelly-bean, installation, insufficient-memory

I bought a smartphone in China, is an OPPO r5, the smartphone has the following settings:

- 4 GB RAM
- Android version: 4.4.2
- Kernel version: eight core MT6592
- Compilation number: MTK 6592
- Personal compilation version: A3SE_AX_CHT_MTZ_4G_V1.1_20141105114604

But when I tap in the android version appears JellyBean Logo (weird because 4.4 is kitkat), when i restore the phone, apears with applications extra and uses 3GB of RAM (without applications starting, and due to this the phone is very slow). The question is if i can install a 'pure version' of kitkat or jellybean version (also a mod) so the smartphone will be faster?
Note: Ir has been checked with antutu and cpuz, is an oppo adn it has an octacore and 4GB ofrece RAM

Comment: Though I don't have an answer for you, [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oppo-r5) has a great development community where you may find what you're looking for. Good luck!

Comment: But can answer could be possible show me Jellybean version if the version showed is 4.4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things which don't sound quite right.

1. **4GB** RAM - The Oppo R5 has **2GB** RAM build in.
2. "eight core MT6592" - R5 uses an Snapdragon SOC. MT6592 is an **Mediatek SOC**.
3. The **Android version**. It doesn't matter which version is shown in the system information. It's a simple edit in /system/**build.prop**. Everyone can write whatever they want.

With these things in mind I think you have bought a fake R5.
So can you change to Cyanogenmod? **No.** By installing the cyanogenmod for the official R5 you might **brick your device** as the kernel is not fitting your hardware.

[Link to the official product page of the R5](http://www.oppo.com/en/smartphone-r5/)

Comment: It's an original OPPO (the startup) and it has 4GB (check it with CPUz), it's clear it could be a fake r5. Is it possible install it kitkat or not?

Comment: Well I don't think it is possible just by the fact that I can't tell for sure if you have an original Oppo R5. The hardware differs alot so I think its a  fake phone. Because of this you won't be able to find a rom for your specific device so again, no, you can't install kitkat. 
What you CAN do is to make a benchmark (antutu benchmark in the playstore) and give us your test result. That way we can have a look at the actual performance and it might be easier to tell if it is fake.

Comment: +1 Good thing. You can add the official link to support your claim. [Here it is](http://www.oppo.com/en/smartphone-r5/). // @fsalazar_sch See the official link. If things differ, then you would have the answer right in front of you.